# Impulse response of a system in z domain

Tags: discrete-signals, linear-systems, z-transform, impulse-response

The question 3-23 in the "Discrete-Time Signal Processing - Second Edition" is:

[image]

and the solution is:

[image]

I cannot understand the solution.  In the second row of the answer when I multiply (-4)  with this denominator:

[image]

and then add the result to:
[image]
it gives a result different from the numerator of the first row. This multiplication must be equal to

[image]

Which is not. Is this solution true? If yes, can anyone help me to understand if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right.

In the solution, the second line which performs the long division

$$ H(z) = -4 + \frac{ 5 + \frac{7}{2} z^{-1} }{1 - \frac{3}{4}z^{-1} + \frac{1}{8} z^{-1} } $$

is **wrong** and should be **corrected** as:

$$ H(z) = -4 + \frac{ 5 - 3 z^{-1} }{1 - \frac{3}{4}z^{-1} + \frac{1}{8} z^{-1} } .$$

However, the partial fraction expansion at the following third line is correct; indicating there was a typo in the second line. Finally, the **impulse response** (which is based on line three) is also **correct**.